# How to alternate between multiple async functions with "loop.run_until_complete()" in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, concurrency, python-asyncio

I'm trying to run **2 async functions `test1()` and `test2()`** with [**loop.run_until_complete()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_until_complete) alternately in Python as shown below:

```py
import asyncio

async def test1():
    for _ in range(3):
        print("Test1")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        
async def test2():
    for _ in range(3):
        print("Test2")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

loop.run_until_complete(test1()) # Here
loop.run_until_complete(test2()) # Here
```

But as shown below, they don't run with [**loop.run_until_complete()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_until_complete) alternately:

```
Test1
Test1
Test1
Test2
Test2
Test2
```

I know that if I use [**loop.run_forever()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_forever) with [**loop.create_task()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_task) as shown below:

```py
import asyncio

async def test1(loop):
    for _ in range(3):
        print("Test1")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        loop.stop() # Extra code to stop "loop.run_forever()"
        
async def test2(loop):
    for _ in range(3):
        print("Test2")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        loop.stop() # Extra code to stop "loop.run_forever()"

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

loop.create_task(test1(loop)) # Here
loop.create_task(test2(loop)) # Here
loop.run_forever() # Here
```

I can run them alternately as shown below but [**loop.run_forever()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_forever) runs forever so to stop [**loop.run_forever()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_forever), **the extra code [loop.stop()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.stop)** is needed which is troublesome. In addition, I know that [**asyncio.gather()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) can also run them alternately but it needs **`await`** which I don't want:

```
Test1
Test2
Test1
Test2
Test1
Test2
```

So, how can I run them with [**loop.run_until_complete()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_until_complete) alternately?

Comment: why don't you want `await`? All async was constructed to use `await` functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you wouldn't insist on the `loop.run_until_complete` you can achieve what you want to get by using the `asyncio.gather` functionality, just like so:

```
import asyncio

async def test1():
    for _ in range(3):
        print("Test1")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def test2():
    for _ in range(3):
        print("Test2")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():
    tasks = [test1(), test2()]
    new_items = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return new_items


if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = asyncio.run(main())
```

and the results would be as you'd expect-

```
==> python3 stack_overflow.py 
Test1
Test2
Test1
Test2
Test1
Test2
```

Comment: "asyncio.gather()" needs "await". I want the code without "await" actually.

Answer (score 0):

You can run **2 async functions `test1()` and `test2()`** alternately by calling **the intermediate async function `call_tests()`** with [**loop.run_until_complete()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_until_complete) as shown below. You also need to use [**asyncio.get_running_loop()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_running_loop) and [**loop.create_task()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_task) in **`call_tests()`** and **`await`** is needed for **the last [loop.create_task()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_task)** to run them alternately as shown below:

```py
import asyncio

async def test1():
    for _ in range(3):
        print("Test1")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        
async def test2():
    for _ in range(3):
        print("Test2")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def call_tests(): # Here
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop() # Here
    loop.create_task(test1()) # Here
    await loop.create_task(test2()) # "await" is needed

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

loop.run_until_complete(call_tests()) # Call "call_tests()"
```

Finally, you can run them alternately as shown below:

```
Test1
Test2
Test1
Test2
Test1
Test2
```

Be careful, if using **`await`** for **the first and last [loop.create_task()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_task) both** as shown below:

```py
# ...

async def call_tests():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    await loop.create_task(test1()) # Here
    await loop.create_task(test2()) # Here

# ...
```

You cannot run them alternately as shown below:

```
Test1
Test1
Test1
Test2
Test2
Test2
```

And, if using **`await`** for **the first [loop.create_task()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_task)** as shown below:

```py
# ...

async def call_tests():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    await loop.create_task(test1()) # Here
    loop.create_task(test2())

# ...
```

You cannot run them alternately and **the last `loop.create_task()`** is exited without completed as shown below:

```
Test1
Test1
Test1
Test2
```

And, if not using **`await`** for **the first and last [loop.create_task()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_task) both** as shown below:

```py
# ...

async def call_tests():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    loop.create_task(test1()) # No "await"
    loop.create_task(test2()) # No "await"

# ...
```

You can run them alternately but **the first and last `loop.create_task()` both** are exited without completed as shown below:

```
Test1
Test2
```

In addition, if using **`asyncio.gather()`**, **`call_tests()`** is not needed as shown below:

```py
import asyncio

async def test1():
    for _ in range(3):
        print("Test1")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        
async def test2():
    for _ in range(3):
        print("Test2")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(test1(), test2()))
```

Then, you can run them alternately as shown below:

```
Test1
Test2
Test1
Test2
Test1
Test2
```